kernel compiling "out of memory" -> kernel panic
I decided to recompile the latest kernel config-6.1.0-28-amd64 of my debian 12.
Everything went fine but once I rebooted the system it returned me a kernel panic after a laconic "out of memory". The initrd is actually huge but I have 36 GB of ram and it shouldn't be a problem.
The following are the monitor's dumps:
Loading Linux 6.12.5
Loading initial ramdisk ...
error: out of memory.

Press any key to continue...

and
[...]
Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on "UUID=b704193c-6f59-46cd-bd15"
CPU: 4 PID: 1 Comm: swapper/0 Not tainted 6.12.5 #3
Hardware name: Acer Nitro AN515-55/Ignis_ADH, BIOS U2.13 03/08/2024
[...]
Kernel Offset: 0x1ea00000 from 0xffffff811000000 (relocation range: 0xffffff8118e00000-0xffffff81f0000000)

it says that it cannot find the root fs but it actually is where it is looking it for. here's the fstab
UUID=b704193c-6f59-46cd-bd19-5b3b59a96f2b /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1

and I compiled the ext4 driver
any suggestion?
thanks in advance

assuming GRUB bootloader and BIOS boot (the old one not UEFI). how large is your initrd? because GRUB may not be able to address all of 36 GB to load the large initrd as GRUB for BIOS boot is only 32-bit capable (so capped to 4 GB of memory)

Something to consider, if you compile all the drivers needed to load the root filesystem into the kernel, instead of as modules, you can skip having a ramfs which would potentially bypass your problems.
